# Server Error - HTTP 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) Only when visiting this one PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am a beginner at PHP, I have made a few pages which insert into my MySQL DB, as well as retrieve. This one page always gives me the 500 error, but my other PHP pages dont (Such as the INSERT record).
Running PHP 5.2, apache 2.2

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "XXXX", "XXXX");
if (!$con) 
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
  mysql_select_db("equipment", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM equipmentwanted");

while $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
echo $row['fname'] . " " . $row['lname'];
echo "<br />";
    }

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Look at your server's error log. It'll have details about the 500. What you see in the browser is deliberately vague.

Comment: This `while $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` to `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`.

Answer (score 4):

Some things to look at:

1) Not checking for query failures:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM equipmentwanted") or die(mysql_error());
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  mysql_select_db("equipment", $con) or die(mysql_error());
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

2) Syntax error:

```
while $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      ^--- missing a (
```

Comment: I thought I had turned on error reporting so I can see the error on my browser...via php.ini. Thanks though, this helped.